# Xcode AFHTTPSessionManager.h file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm a newcomer to Xcode and native iOS development, having had previous experience on Android native and React native. I inherited an Objective-C codebase for an iOS application, which has not been touched for about 2 years. I tried to build the project on an iOS simulator, but I encountered this error during the build.

I have seen quite a few posts on StackOverflow where "xxxx.h" file is not found, however, I was unable to find a definitive solution. As you can see in the screenshots below, the AFHTTPSessionManager.h file is indeed in the Pods folder, however, for some reason, the header file just cannot be found.

What I have tried is to add the full path of where the file is found into the Header Search in the build settings for both the project and the pods directory.

Some help is very much appreciated so I can start working on the project. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you're importing files inside your module/framework, you use `#import "file.h"`

But when you need to use an instance defined in an other framework, you can't do that. You need to import that framework header file, in this case `#import <AFNetworking.h>`, or `@import AFNetworking;`

Comment: Hi Philip, thank you for the reply. Your comment helped me get past the original problem that I faced. However, there is a new problem. In the pod right below AFNetworking, I got the exact same problem as in the original, and this time, your suggestions did not work. I have edited my original post to include the new issues. I really hope that you can help me again. Thank you.

Comment: @Keith I just trying installing this pod and `#import <HTPressableButton.h>` works totally fine. Not sure what's your problem, check out build log